# Index data structure for RavenDB

Tags: indexing, ravendb, b-tree

Both MongoDB and CouchDB use B-trees as an underlying data structure for storing indexes. Anyone knows what is the equivalent for RavenDB? There is nothing mentioned about this in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: This question is not about MongoDB or couchDB, it merely mentions them in passing as such I have removed those tags

Answer (score 2):

RavenDB uses Lucene index.

> In order to allow fast queries over your indexes, RavenDB processes
>   them in the background, executing the queries against the stored
>   documents and persisting the results to a Lucene index. Lucene is a
>   full text search engine library (Raven uses the .NET version) which
>   allows us to perform lightning fast full text searches.

You can read more about indexing in the documentation: [How the indexes work](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/appendixes/lucene-indexes-usage)